# MySQL find_in_set() function skips an item in the set

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a very strange issue with the MySQL find_in_set() function.  Three tables, as follows.  The query at the bottom is looking for all users whose positions are listed in activity_assoc for the particular activity.  In other words: "Which people have this activity?".

It *should* find all three users; but for some reason it skips the position in the middle, and only returns user 1 and 3. (Actual data has more people. It is clearly skipping a particular position -- as though "DOP" were not on the list in `activity_assoc`.`positions`.)

users_master

```
id    first_name        last_name        position_id
----------------------------------------------------------- 
1     Eblis             O'Shaugnessy     13
2     JimmyJojo         Shamadou         20
3     Bob               Justbob          25
```

positions

```
id    position              abbreviation
---------------------------------------------
13    Director of Stuff     DOS
20    Director of Peoples   DOP
25    Director of Ideas     DOI
```

activity_assoc

```
id    activity              positions
----------------------------------------------
47    Make Things Happen    DOS,DOP,DOI
```

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `users`.`id`, `users`.`first_name`, `last_name`, `position`, `activity_assoc`.`positions`
FROM `activity_assoc`, 
    ( 
        SELECT `users_master`.*, `positions`.`abbreviation` AS `position`
        FROM `users_master` LEFT JOIN `positions` ON `users_master`.`position_id` = `positions`.`id` 
    ) AS `users`
WHERE 
    `activity_assoc`.`activity` = 'Make Things Happen' AND
    find_in_set( `users`.`position`, `activity_assoc`.`positions` )
```

If I change the find_in_set line to the following, it works fine.

```
`users`.`position` IN ( 'DOS','DOP','DOI' )
```

UPDATE: The below part is now fixed:

<strike>You may have noticed the `cast()` function. If I leave that off I get an "illegal mix of collations" error.  Most tables in the DB are `utf8_general_ci`, but the activity_assoc table was `utf8_unicode_ci`. I ran the following in it yesterday to try and fix this:</strike>

```
ALTER TABLE `activity_assoc` COLLATE `utf8_general_ci`;
```

The Table Inspector in MySQL Workbench now shows it as `utf8_general_ci` collation, but actually running the query seems to act as though it's still `utf8_unicode_ci`. (To be clear: Table Inspector currently shows all three tables to be `utf8_general_ci` collation.)  I can't tell if these are two separate problems or the same problem.

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are not storing lists of codes in a string.

Comment: Changing the character set or collation of a table doesn't convert existing columns, it just sets a table-level default, in case you add new columns in the future. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html about `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET...`

Comment: @BillKarwin - That fixed the Cast() issue -- thanks!

Comment: Check if it also resolves the join after you fix the character set and collation. I tested it and it seems to work fine in my environment.

Comment: After beating against it for a few hours it basically corrected itself.  It appears it may have been some minor corruption to the DB record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BillKarwin resolved one issue I was having, and the main issue of the find_in_set() not working properly suddenly started working after I manually altered the record (probably not for the first time).  Can't say why or how -- some sort of glitch at the DB or system level. :-/